# How do I make a bullet fire?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I don't know what to do next.
Right now when I click, it adds the bullet and rotates it to the correct angle, but I don't know how to make it fire. I want to have the bullet shoot to where the mouse is pointing. Thanks!
PS: Sorry if the code is messy.

```
package    
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.text.Font;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextDisplayMode;
    import flash.text.TextExtent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import fl.motion.easing.Back;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class GameEnter extends MovieClip
    {

        public var _bullet:bullet;

        public function GameEnter() 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootBullet);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, removeBullet);
        }

        public function init()
        {
            _bullet = new bullet();
            addChild(_bullet);

            _bullet.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            _bullet.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
        }

        public function onEnter(event:Event)
        {
            var dx:Number = mouseX - _bullet.x;
            var dy:Number = mouseY - _bullet.y;
            var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy,dx) * 180 / Math.PI;

            _bullet.rotation = angle;
        }

        public function shootBullet(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            init();
        }

        public function removeBullet(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            removeChild(_bullet);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move an object in a direction based on rotation, you'll need `cos` and `sin`.

`Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` only accept radians, so you'll need to convert rotation to radians like you have for `Math.atan2()` in your example.

Sample:

```
// Note: Utilising the property 'angle' from your code.
_bullet.x += Math.cos(angle);
_bullet.y += Math.sin(angle);
```

And then obviously multiply these values by a value that will represent how fast you want the bullet to go, eg:

```
var velocity:Number = 10.5;

_bullet.x += Math.cos(angle) * velocity;
_bullet.y += Math.sin(angle) * velocity;
```